# How can I know whether process has a windows or not?

Tags: powershell

Sometimes my program is finished incorrectly. GUI is gone but processes still present in the system. So I need to verify whether the program finishes correctly or not by checking GUI presence. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: `I need to verify whether the program finishes correctly or not by checking GUI presence.` But you also say your program finishes incorrectly when this happens. So which is it? I wouldn't recommend checking for a "correctly" finished process by the presence of a GUI

Comment: I've googled it but I failed to find anything worth.

Comment: acro444, "my app" means an app. I'm not able to work with its code. I just want to get the state of this app whether it starts/finishes correctly or not. I believe this is the only way to find out for sure if it does. I realize it's a crutch, but... :)

Comment: This is unclear to me with what information is shown. All I can suggest so far is: `Get-Process myapp` and if you get a return then it is still running. That wont know if the GUI is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/).

You can use WASP's `Select-Window` to list all window handles.

You can then use `Select-Window Myapp*` to set focus on the window, if required.